# Populating a URL from a drop down menu

Tags: html, form-submit

I am very new to this sort of thing and am trying to think of a way to make this work. I want to have users select options from a drop down menu, and when they click the search button, have them go to a URL that was created based off of their selections. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated, thank you all.

Code so far:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="">
<table>
<tbody><tr><th align="left">Type:</th><td>
<select name="type">
<option selected="">Comforter <!-- This selection would have this piece of the URL: #/?attr-__Domestics__TypeOfBedCoverIncluded=Comforter -->
</option><option>Duvet
</option><option>Bedspread
</option></select><br>
</td></tr><tr><th align="left">Bed Size:</th><td>
<select name="bed size">
<option selected="">California King <!-- This selection would have this piece of the URL: &attr-__Domestics__BedSize=California King -->
</option><option>Full
</option><option>King
</option></select><br>
</td></tr><tr><th align="left">Brand:</th><td>
<select name="brand">
<option selected="">Alcove <!-- This selection would have this piece of the URL: &attr-__General__Brand=Alcove -->
</option><option>Lush Decor
</option><option>Non Branded
</option></select>
</td></tr></tbody></table>
<p><input type="SUBMIT" value="Search">
<!-- This button when submitted would go here: blahblah.com/cat_7986/Mcatg/cat_3/139.uts/ ***The end of this URL would be populated from the dropdown selections*** -->
</p></form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Change the `<input type="submit" value="Search" />`
to: `<input id="submitForm" type="SUBMIT" value="Search">`
Change also : `<select name="bed size">` to `<select name="bedSize">`

And add some JavaScript:

```
var myFunction = function() {
  var stringConstruction = document.getElementsByName('type')[0].value + "/" + document.getElementsByName('bedSize')[0].value + "/" + document.getElementsByName('brand')[0].value;

  alert(stringConstruction);
}

document.getElementById("submitForm").addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

Here is an exemple:

https://jsfiddle.net/mbkqbd91/

EDIT: Your request is:

> I want to go to this URL: blahblah.com/cat_7986/Mcatg/cat_3/139.uts/#/?attr-__Domestics__TypeOfBedCoverInclu‌​ded=Comforter&attr-__Domestics__BedSize=California King&attr-__General__Brand=Alcove When the search button is clicked, rather than a popup box showing

So the code would be:

```
 var myFunction = function() {
     var stringConstruction = 'blahblah.com/cat_7886/Mcatg/cat_3/139.uts/#/?attr-__Domestics__TypeOfBedCoverIncluded=' 
     + document.getElementsByName('type')[0].value 
     + '&attr-__Domestics__BedSize=' 
     + document.getElementsByName('bedSize')[0].value 
     + '&attr-__General__Brand=' 
     +  document.getElementsByName('brand')[0].value;

  window.location = stringConstruction;
}

document.getElementById("submitForm").addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, however I want to go to this URL: blahblah.com/cat_7986/Mcatg/cat_3/139.uts/#/?attr-__Domestics__TypeOfBedCoverIncluded=Comforter&attr-__Domestics__BedSize=California King&attr-__General__Brand=Alcove

When the search button is clicked, rather than a popup box showing.

Comment: B-e-a-utiful. That is just what I needed! Thank you very much @Didier Aupest!

Comment: If this is the answer you are looking for, can you, please, mark this as the answer ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

var myFunction = function() {
     var stringConstruction = 'blahblah.com/cat_7886/Mcatg/cat_3/139.uts/#/?attr-__Domestics__TypeOfBedCoverIncluded=' 
     + document.getElementsByName('type')[0].value 
     + '&attr-__Domestics__BedSize=' 
     + document.getElementsByName('bedSize')[0].value 
     + '&attr-__General__Brand=' 
     +  document.getElementsByName('brand')[0].value;

window.location = stringConstruction;
}

document.getElementById("submitForm").addEventListener('click', myFunction);